# Eel python: Javascript error eel is not a function

Tags: javascript, python, html, eel

I am using eel to communicate with python. I'm working in dir `C:\Users\Desktop\Eel` where I have `app.py` and inside the `UI` folder I have `index.html, myjava.js, style.css, images` but nothing called `eel.js`. I said this because in docs it says to include script called `/eel.js`.

---

**index.html**

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript" src="./myjava.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/eel.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
```

```
<body>
<div class="container" onclick="runeel()">
</body>
```

my Javascript is:

```
function runeel(){
    eel.runpy()
}
```

**app.py**

```
import eel

eel.init('UI')
eel.start('index.html', size=(900, 550))

@eel.expose
def runpy():
     ....code which creates an excel file in desktop...
```

When I run the py file, the index.html loads up and then when I click the div I get into the function and but it throws the error:

```
myjava.js:2 Uncaught TypeError: eel.runpy is not a function
```

What am I missing?

Comment: I have put the eel script tag at the end of the body in the past instead of in the head

Comment: maybe instead of eel.runpy(), just runpy(), but i really don't know. ‍♀️

Comment: Does your eel script keep running after you start it?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the init statement is written first.
What about writing the @eel.expose statement right after the import statement?

I'm not good at English, so I'm worried that it will make sense.
But I would be happy if I could help.

Comment: It was a sentence, not a statement.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had to start `eel` *after* exposing the function via the decorator:

```
import eel

eel.init('UI')

@eel.expose
def runpy():
     ....code which creates an excel file in desktop...

eel.start('index.html', size=(900, 550))
```

Answer (score 0):

i had the same problem until I removed the /eel.js from

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/eel.js"></script>
```

now it's look like

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="eel.js"></script>
```